# Slow laptop and missing firmwares

Tags: drivers, firmware

I have installed Xbuntu on my laptop and it's very slow at times. I suspect that I don't have the correct drivers for both my GPU and my wifi NIC since it's getting incredibly slow when I'm on the internet and trying to watch a video (with VLC) at the same time. And I have a 100% pixeled screen just before Linux is loading then it's OK.

Also, I'm getting the following warning when doing sudo apt-get upgrade

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega10_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_cap.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/gc_11_0_0_toc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

I have installed Xubuntu and selected the option with less gizmos. I'm going to include as many info as possible so you guys can help.

HARWARE (from CPU-X)

```
AMD E-240 processor (Brazos Zacate)
AMD Radeon HD 6310 (Wrestler) UMD version: Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1)
It's my understanding that the CPU and GPU are combined into one chipset.
```

```
sudo uname -m: x86_64
```

KERNEL

```
Linux version 5.19.0-32-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-026) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jan 30 17:03:34 UTC 2
```

OS (I've installed Xubuntu)

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

sudo lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation Family 14h Processor Root Complex
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation Wrestler [Radeon HD 6310]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 4138 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 414c [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4130 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4148 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4110 [size=16]
    Memory at f0348000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [70] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0347000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    Memory at f0346000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [e4] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00e0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0345000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    Memory at f0344000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [e4] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00e0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SBx00 SMBus Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]

00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f0200000-f02fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
    Capabilities: [b8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=06, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f0100000-f01fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
    Capabilities: [b8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [f0] Secure device <?>
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
    Flags: fast devsel

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-91-81-fe-ff-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce

06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at f0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [6c] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] Device Serial Number ff-9c-8c-3d-00-26-6c-ff
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
    Kernel modules: atl1c
```

Two things from lspci -v
First, it seems the GPU drivers are OK. However, I'm still getting a warning about missing firmeware when doing apt-get upgrade.

Second, I noticed the Wifi is RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01), but the drivers in use are Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce

So, where to get the missing firmwares and do I just copy the files in the directpry and that's it? And how to make sure I have the 100% correct drivers, and if not, how to install the correct ones. Last, is there anything else that could slow down my laptop? It's been like that right from the fresh install.

Thanks in advance for your kind help!